# how to specify which files should be uploaded onn file upload using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I am uploading files onto a folder within my application using the code below. I would like to know how I can specify which type of files can be uploaded into that folder in my case I only want the user to be able to upload xls,xlxs and csv files. The user should not be allowed to upload docx or images etc

```
function OnUpload(evt) {
        var files = $("#fileUpload").get(0).files;
        if (files.length > 0) {

            ShowUploadProgress();

            if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
                var data = new FormData();
                for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    data.append("file" + i, files[i]);
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    //url: "/api/ExcelBulkUpload",
                    url: "/api/FileUpload",
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: data,
                    success: function (results) {
                        ShowUploadControls();
                        $("#uploadResults").empty();
                        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                            $("#uploadResults").append($("<li/>").text(results[i]));
                        }
                        ///"location.href='<%: Url.Action("Upload", "Controller") %>'"
                           window.location.href = '@Url.Action("UploadPage", "Home")';
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        ShowUploadControls();
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("Your browser doesn't support HTML5 multiple file uploads! Please use another browser.");
            }
        }
    }



   What I have researched so far




_validFileExtensions = [".xls", ".xlsx"];
var sFileName = oInput.value;
            if (sFileName.length > 0) {
               var blnValid = false;
               for (var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
                  var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
                  if (sFileName.substr(sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length, sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()) {
                     blnValid = true;
                     //$('#fileinput').val('');

                     break;
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check file extension, and based on that if file extension are allowed then call upload function, else display message that selected file not allowed to upload.

Se below example.

**Note** : Only client side validation is not enough, also put validation on server side.

```js
$(document).on("change","#myfile", function (e) {

            var _theFormFile = $('#myfile')[0].files[0];
            var ext = getExt(_theFormFile.name);
            if(ext == ".xls" || ext == ".xlxs " || ext == ".csv") {
               alert('call upload file function');
            } else {
                alert('display false message')
                return false;
            }
            
            
        });
        
        
        function getExt(filename) {
                var ext = filename.split(".");
                var cnt = ext.length;
                ext = ext[cnt - 1];
                ext = "." + ext.toLowerCase();
                return ext;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='file' name="myfile" id="myfile">
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can select what file types the users can input by default with

```
<input accept=".fileType" />
```

And then check the filetyp if they changed the filter

```js
function upload(){
 var fileName = document.getElementById("file").files[0].name; 
 console.log(fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")));
}
```

```html
<input id="file" type="file" accept=".xls,.xlxs,.csv" />
<button onClick="upload()">send</button>
```